# testHarness timer not getting deleted in flink 1.8.2

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using testHarness to test my Custom Trigger. The simplified snippet is attached below:

```java
public class CustomTrigger extends Trigger<InputPOJO, TimeWindow> {

    private final ReducingStateDescriptor<Long> previousTriggerDesc = new ReducingStateDescriptor<>( "previous-trigger", new Max(),LongSerializer.INSTANCE);

    private final long allowedLatenessMillis;


    public CustomTrigger(long allowedLatenessMillis) {
        this.allowedLatenessMillis = allowedLatenessMillis;
    }


    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(InputPOJO inputPOJO, long timestamp, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {

        ReducingState<Long> previousTriggerState = ctx.getPartitionedState(previousTriggerDesc);
        Long previousTriggerTime = ctx.getPartitionedState(previousTriggerDesc).get();

        // Remove previous Timer trigger. else it will invoke twice.
        if (previousTriggerTime != null) {
            ctx.deleteProcessingTimeTimer(previousTriggerTime); //NOTE
            System.out.println("deleteProcessingTimeTimer(previousTriggerTime)"+previousTriggerTime); // Invoked
        }

        // register new trigger for current InputPOJO.      
        long currentTriggerTime = ctx.getCurrentProcessingTime() + allowedLatenessMillis;
        ctx.registerProcessingTimeTimer(currentTriggerTime);

        // Update currentTriggerTime in previousTriggerState.
        previousTriggerTimeState.add(currentTriggerTime);

        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    ...
}
```

In the custom trigger, I am registering a new timer for every new InputPOJO. When I am registering the timer, I am deleting the previous timer (based on the previousTimerTriggerTime, saved in the reduced state).

I am testing the timer count (along with window), using the below snippet.

```java
private OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<InputPOJO, OutputPOJO> testHarness;

private CustomWindowFunction customWindowFunction;

@Before
public void setup_testHarness() throws Exception {

    KeySelector<InputPOJO, String> keySelector = InputPOJO::getKey;

    TypeInformation<InputPOJO> STRING_INT_TUPLE = TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<InputPOJO>() {}); // Any suggestion ?

    ListStateDescriptor<InputPOJO> stateDesc = new ListStateDescriptor<>("window-contents", STRING_INT_TUPLE.createSerializer(new ExecutionConfig())); // Any suggestion ?

    /**
     * Creating windowOperator for the below function
     *
     * <pre>
     *
     *      DataStream<OutputPOJO> OutputPOJOStream =
     *         inputPOJOStream
     *             .keyBy(InputPOJO::getKey)
     *             .window(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(triggerMaximumTimeoutSeconds)))
     *             .trigger(new CustomTrigger(triggerAllowedLatenessMillis))
     *             .process(new CustomWindowFunction(windowListStateTtlMillis));
     * </pre>
     */
    customWindowFunction = new CustomWindowFunction(secondsToMillis(windowListStateTtlMillis));

    WindowOperator<String, InputPOJO, Iterable<InputPOJO>, OutputPOJO, TimeWindow>
        operator =
            new WindowOperator<>(
                // setting .window(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(maxTimeout))
                ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(triggerMaximumTimeoutSeconds)),
                new TimeWindow.Serializer(),
                // setting .keyBy(InputPOJO::getKey)
                keySelector,
                BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO.createSerializer(new ExecutionConfig()),
                stateDesc,
                // setting  .process(new CustomWindowFunction(windowListStateTtlMillis))
                new InternalIterableProcessWindowFunction<>(CustomWindowFunction),
                // setting .trigger(new CustomTrigger(allowedLateness))
                new CustomTrigger(secondsToMillis(allowedLatenessSeconds)),
                0,
                null);

    // Creating testHarness for window operator
    testHarness = new KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<>(operator, keySelector, BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO);

    // Setup and Open  Test Harness
    testHarness.setup();

    testHarness.open();
}


@Test
public void test_allowedLateness_extension_on_second_pojo() throws Exception {

    int allowedLatenessSeconds = 3;
    int listStateTTL = 10;

    //1. Arrange
    InputPOJO listStateInput1 = new InputPOJO(1,"Arjun");
    InputPOJO listStateInput2 = new InputPOJO(2,"Arun");


    // 2. Act
    // listStateInput1 comes at 1 sec
    testHarness.setProcessingTime(secondsToMillis(1));
    testHarness.processElement(new StreamRecord<>(listStateInput1));

    // listStateInput2 comes at 2 sec, ie in the allowedLateness period of listStateInput1
    testHarness.setProcessingTime(secondsToMillis(2));
    testHarness.processElement(new StreamRecord<>(listStateInput1));

    // Expectation : listStateInput2 deletes the existing untriggered timer of listStateInput1 and registers a new timer. 
    // Actual: listStateInput2 registered a new timer and the total count is 3.
    // NOTE: 
    // 1. Here I am using SessionWindow, so by default 1 timer would be registered for SessionGap.
    // 2. Second timer should be the InputPOJO registered timer.
     Assert.assertEquals(2, testHarness.numProcessingTimeTimers()); // FAILS

}
```

Here, the functions, `ctx.deleteProcessingTimeTimer(previousTriggerTime);`, is getting triggered. But still the timerCount in testHarness is showing 3.

1. Is it a bug in testHarness?
2. Kindly provide an approach to test timer count with testHarness.

PS:

1. Even though this might seem like a typical functionality of SessionWindow.Gap(), I am using this Custom Trigger in a complex calculation. For simplicity, I have reduced the logic to the above mentioned.
2. I am using `ListStateDescriptor` when creating `WindowOperator` for testHarness.